# Modify req.query.page query parameter and compose the new URL string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Node.js + Express project. Working on pagination I want to create the pagination links. Imagine the following URL:

http://server.com/products?page=1&color=red&size=big

I am here:

```
exports.products = function(req, res) {

}
```

I could use req.query.page and req.url and compose new URL for next and previous pages using regex and string functions for increasing/decreasing page parameter, but the question is:

Is there a cleaner method?
Some bodyparser feature?

Comment: I cannot understand why you should use regex and string functions. Can you show us your try?

Comment: I didn't say I used regex and string functions. I am asking for a easier procedure instead. For example the first answer. But anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example (without input validation, but that's left as an exercise):

```
var toQS = require('querystring').stringify;

exports.products = function(req, res) {
  ...
  req.query.page = Number(req.query.page) + 1;
  var newUrl = req.path + '?' + toQS(req.query);
  ...
};
```

Comment: ThankYou I didn't know about 'querystring' module.